# RoR : JQuery and Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am a fan of Ruby on Rails and currently looking into tutorials
about adding AJAX to the page.
I tried [this tutorial](http://eddorre.com/posts/tutorial-filtering-results-with-jquery-ui-slider-and-rails), with the source also there.
I kinda understand the code, but on my computer, after sliding the stock-list does not update and keeps on displaying the entire stock list, but clearly the values are passed around correctly, as I can check it in the controller.

I tried modifying the code and adding JRails in app/views/index.js.erb instead of

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'x_stock_list', :partial => 'stocks/stock_list', :locals => { :stocks => @stocks }
    end
```

or even adding a simple alert js function into this file, but it shows it as plain text, when i force it to use that file (by deleting the 'format.html' line above).
Apparently, the javascript did not get executed.

According to a lot of tutorials by Ryan Bates (RailsCasts) , this line had to be added to
application.js:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({  'beforeSend': function(xhr)
```

{xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}})

to force javascript to get executed, but that did not help either.

Has anybody an idea or is it only on my pc that the slider does not update?

Comment: FYI, an invaluable tool to help you debug your AJAX calls and more is Firebug. All AJAX requests are printed to the console, where you can retrieve all sorts of useful information like the return value, request headers, and so on. The console should be enough for most needs. If you need more fine-tuned data, the Net panel is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your format.html down to the last format in the list. I had this problem a while back and apparently the order matters.

Comment: Thank you, xpx777, apparently that worked. Although in every tutorial so far I did not noticed this reversed order, but ok, now i know it! :) thx